# How to acess an array values?

Tags: c#

I have an array called Cases which has 8 values and each one of them are instantiated through this piece of code:

```
Instantiate(Cases[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 7)], transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
```

Then, I have another array called Images which has 8 sprites. I've created this one, because I got a canvas that has an image component attached to it, and I'd like to put the sprites in this image component, but in the following way:

For instance, if the case number 1 is instantiated, so I wanna take this value from the array Cases and use it in the script that I have the array called Images, in order to use the sprite number 1.

How could I do it?

Comment: Get your random number and pass that around instead of a single case? Though it seems that the cases and the images are intrinsically linked together, why not store them together too?

Comment: How can I get this random number and store it in a variable?

Comment: Like `var randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 7);`. It seems like you are a beginner developer, perhaps running through some tutorials would be more helpful than asking questions here?

Comment: Yes certainly, but you will learn much faster and better if you do some formal training instead of asking here. It would be to your benefit.

Comment: I totally agree man. I don't wanna just copy codes. I do want to learn how to do it. Could you tell me, where I can find good tutorials about it, please? Because there's a lot, but it's kind hard for me to find some that I can really on.